# How can I get iCab under BasiliskII to see the network?

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, mac-os-classic

I am interested in getting iCab, and/or Classilla, to work under a BasiliskII VM with System 8.7.

At present I've gotten iCab to run, but not see the network or load e.g. google.com.

I believe this is because networking is not (adequately) set up in BasiliskII or the guest.

What needs to be done so that a classic Macintosh VM sees the network from a networked Linux host?

TIA,

**--UPDATE--**

Thank you, @HackSlash, for the comments. When I view https://emaculation.com/doku.php/basiliskii_linux_setup online, it says:

> -sudo insmod sheep_net.ko
>   -sudo chown “yourusername” /dev/sheep_net (this prevents you having to run as root to have network access, but you'll have to perform this step every time before starting Basilisk under a non-root account)

However, when I tried to do that I got an error:

```
$ sudo insmod sheep_net.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module sheep_net.ko: Invalid module format
```

This is from a Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia system; I assumed that the Ubuntu driver would be closer than SUSE, but maybe it wasn't close enough.

Advice on which paths to take within the documentation?

Regarding questions on how networking is configured in the host, it is on a NATted LAN behind a server:

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:20:19:a5:16  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d1800000-d1820000 

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:20:19:a5:45  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2097761 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:2097761 (2.0 MB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:a8:a6:0d:94:40  
          inet addr:10.0.255.157  Bcast:10.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::604e:a3dc:1845:6216/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:345317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:306830541 (306.8 MB)  TX bytes:47990622 (47.9 MB)
```

As far as networking on the guest, here are two screenshots from MacTCP, partly configured. I don't know if this is here I should be looking as it is superficially different from the documentation, but I have manual and automatic configuration displayed.

[image: Dynamic configuration of MacTCP]

[image: Static configuration of MacTCP]

Thanks,

Comment: How is the network configured in the host? How is it configured in the guest? Are they in the same subnet? Can you ping the gateway from inside the VM?

Comment: Looks like you need to use the SheepShaver slirp driver. https://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_online_guide

Comment: https://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/basiliskii_linux_setup

Comment: In that screenshot you have your guest IP manually set to `0.0.0.0`, that would be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure we're going to get success on this one... @HackSlash, would you write up what you can in an answer so I can accept it, even if it's not perfect?